# SF Collection Plots in lat/long but Geometry is Not

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, sf, ggplot2

I'm using `urbnmapr` to get a county base map. I want to plot my own points on top of this map. Even though the `urbnmapr` map plots with lat/long on the x y axis, the lat/long points that I want to plot over it do not. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#devtools::install_github("UrbanInstitute/urbnmapr")
library(urbnmapr)
  
counties_sf <- get_urbn_map(map = "counties", sf = TRUE,) %>%
  subset(state_abbv %in% "SC")
  
points <- tibble(x = c(34.95116, 34.95265, 34.95116, 35.07469), 
                 y = c(-82.79619 , -82.79647, -82.79676, -82.63421)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = st_crs(counties_sf))

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = counties_sf)+
  geom_sf(data = points)
```

Here the map of SC is in the right position, but the points are not. Examining the `counties_sf` data, I see their geometry is wacky, while the `points` geometry is not. I'm very confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

- how hard is the requirement to use urbnmapr? the golden standard of accessing US county data is (arguably) [`{tigris}`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tigris). Note that this may not be the real culprit.
- you seem to have the coords wrong in your points object - lat long vs long lat. This seems a bigger issue than the urbnmapr (which I don't have on hand) vs tigris packages.

Or, because an example is more than 1000 words, consider this piece of code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tigris)


counties_sf <- tigris::counties(state = "SC", resolution = "20m")

points <- tibble(x = c(34.95116, 34.95265, 34.95116, 35.07469), 
                 y = c(-82.79619 , -82.79647, -82.79676, -82.63421)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("y", "x"), crs = st_crs(counties_sf))

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = counties_sf) +
  geom_sf(data = points, pch = 4, color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thanks. I was wondering why I couldn't find a standard program for US boundaries in SF format. Thanks for pointing me there.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate numbers you feed to `points` are in lat-long, but you then tell `sf` that these numbers are the same coordinate system as your boundaries.

What you should do is tell `sf` these are in lat-long (which is normally the EPSG code 4326, unless you know that these locations are not EPSG 4326, aka WGS 84, aka "GPS Coordinates"), and also get `x` and `y` the right way round:

```
points <- st_as_sf(
    data.frame(
      x = c(34.95116, 34.95265, 34.95116, 35.07469), 
      y = c(-82.79619 , -82.79647, -82.79676, -82.63421)
    ), coords=c("y","x"), crs=4326)
```

[image]